# Sprite Kit Remove SKNode From Parent When Off Screen

Tags: sprite-kit, removechild, skspritenode, sknode

I would like to know how to remove my SKNodes when they are off screen to help my game run more smoothly.

#### How To Do This On Sprite Kit

Thanks So Much

Comment: Show the attempts you've already made at doing this yourself.

Comment: See this answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29351327/1966109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195006/2494064

Here is a link to an answer that removes nodes that go off the top of the screen.  You would just have to replicate this to cover the entire border and set all of the walls to have the same contactBitMask values.

Basically the logic is to remove the SKSpriteNodes when they contact physicsbodies that you have resting just outside the visible screen.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to be of assistance.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy solution in Swift 4:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let s = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      s.text = "test"
      s.fontSize = 50
      addChild(s)

      let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 40, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
      s.run(SKAction.repeatForever(moveRight))
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        if ((s.parent != nil) && !intersects(s)) {
            s.removeFromParent()
            print("Sprite removed.")
        }
    }
}
```

You have a sprite (in this case a `SKLabelNode` but any sprite node will do) that is moving horizontally and you want to delete this sprite once is out of the frame bounds.

You can use the `intersects` function to check this and then remove that sprite from its parent. I have also checked that the sprite has a parent before removing it (by checking if `s.parent` is not nil) as we wish to remove the sprite only once.