# How to delete object after it gone outside the scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to delete the objects after it go outside the scene so so i can extenuate ram consumption

I should put the code i have tried but i dont know how to begin so i have nothing to put here sorry

**EDIT**

Or maybe i should detect if the object inside the view and delete it if not how i can know if the object is inside the view ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a convenient method which checks whether two CGRects intersect each other or not

You can do something like this

```
if( CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, view.frame) ) {
   // Don't delete your object
} else {
   // Delete your object as it is not in your view
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check in different ways if node is off-screen, and that depends on how you move nodes.

First method :

```
if (!intersectsNode(yourNode)) {
     // node is off-screen
}
```

To enumerate nodes you can use : 
[- enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) To access all nodes in a node tree read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749743/3402095).

Another way is to use actions:

```
let move = SKAction.moveTo(location: offScreenLocation, duration: 5)

let remove = SKAction.runBlock({yourNode.removeFromParent()})

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move,remove])

yourNode.runAction(sequence, withKey:"moving") //Use action with key, to cancel the action if needed
```

Third method would be to use [contact detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24169882/3402095).